# Is it possible to deploy an Adobe AIR desktop application to iOS?

Tags: ios, air, flash-builder4.5

I have an incredibly basic Adobe AIR 4.5 desktop project that I just want to use to test an iOS deployment. Is it at all possible to deploy this to an iOS device as it is? Or does it need to be turned into a Mobile project somehow?

The steps to creating an IPA file in the guide on Adobe's site (http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-ios.html) seem to assume the project is already a mobile project. I'm a total newb here, but it sounds like this sort of thing is possible? Is it really? I'm having trouble finding information.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a simple Flash project and export it without modification for iOS. Obviously depending on what the project is doing, some things might need to be tweaked.

I am currently building several apps using the same fla and as files, which are targetted for browser and iOS use.

But in order to place anything onto an iDevice, be it just for debugging, testing or adHoc distribution, you need to be signed up to the Apple Development program, have an Apple provisioning certificate in place and have relevant apple provisioning profiles created.

There is a great course on lynda.com about setting yourself up for iDevice app building.

http://www.lynda.com/iOS-SDK-4-tutorials/distributing-ios-applications-through-the-app-store/77853-2.html?srchtrk=index%3A7%0Alinktypeid%3A2%0Aq%3Aios%0Apage%3A1%0As%3Arelevance%0Asa%3Atrue%0Aproducttypeid%3A2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, it the project doesn't need to be a mobile project? You can do this with a desktop project? Or, do I need to create a new mobile project and reuse the files. If so, can you explain how to do it. I understand deploying to the phone typically, but Air apps are more complicated.

Comment: Once you have created your swf and tested it:

For a Mac app or PC exe file click the Publish Settings button in the Properties panel, then under Publish, Other Formats: tick the Mac and/or PC projector checkbox, then hit Publish.

Alternatively to export an AIR app, again in the Properties panel, change the player to AIR 2.6 or whatever version you are working with, hit the Publish Settings Button and then click Publish. You will then be asked to create a certificate along with a few other options.